# Proportion and Averaging Data

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am brand new to r and I am trying to calculate the proportion of the number of 'i' for each timepoint and then average them. I do not know the command for this but I have the script to find the total number of 'i' in the time points.

```
C1imask<-C16.3[,2:8]== 'i'&!is.na(C16.3[,2:8])
C16.3[,2:8][C1imask]
C1inactive<-C16.3[,2:8][C1imask]
length(C1inactive)

C1bcmask<-C16.3[,8]== 'bc'&!is.na(C16.3[,8])
C16.3[,8][C1bcmask]
C1broodcare<-C16.3[,8][C1bcmask]
length(C1broodcare)

C1amask<-C16.3[,12]== 'bc'&!is.na(C16.3[,12])
C16.3[,12][C1amask]
C1after<-C16.3[,12][C1amask]
length(C1after)

  
C1<-length(C1after)-length(C1broodcare)
C1
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It's not an issue with the code I am just not sure what commands are needed to find the the proportions of columns 2-8 and the average of all of that data efficiently

Comment: It's an issue for anyone writing code to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try taking the mean of a logical vector created with the test. You would use na.rm as an argument to `mean`. You will get the proportion of non-NA values that meet the test rather than the proportion of with number of rows as the denominator.

```
test <- sample( c(0,1,NA), 100, replace=TRUE)

mean( test==0, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 0.5072464
```

If you needed a proportion of total number of rows you would use `sum` and divide by `nrow(dframe_name)`. You can then use `sapply` or `lapply` to iterate across a group of columns.